# Integrating PostgreSQL with git/Gitlab

Tags: sql, git, postgresql

I wonder if there is a tool that will help my team to keep a git repository (that we host on Gitlab) to synchronize with our PostgreSQL database.

The idea is that the code used to create tables and views should be versioned and that I'd like to create a few pipelines to make inspections on SQL code and some quirks of our database. But if anything would allow me to compare versions of DDLs in a git repository without manual intervention I'd be happy already.